# Docker: Mount volume from Windows host

Tags: windows, docker, docker-volume

I use 1.12 version of Docker on Windows, since I can't use the Hyper-V feature with the newer "native" version - so I have my quickstart terminal and communicate to docker host via the invisible underlying virtual box.

Now I have the problem, that I need to mount a local folder to a container, which worked successfully from within the docker-machine by adding

```
--volume="`pwd`:/root/data"
```

to the docker run command, but it does not when I launch the same command from my Windows quickstart terminal (even though `pwd` command works correctly in the terminal).

I tried to find the Windows specific settings for the directory and tested several combinations of format, but no luck. Can anyone help me out on how to correctly specify a Windows folder (e.g. `C:\Users\alexander.ruehl`) for the volume parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative path for your volume : `--volume="./mydata:/root/data"`

Also make sure that you have given the permission for read/write to Docker.

[image]