# Docker mount host volume Windows

Tags: docker

I'm using `Windows 10` and `Docker version 18.03.1-ce`, build 9ee9f40.

I'm trying to do `docker run -it --volume="./Users:/app" ubuntu:16.04` or `docker run -it -v Users:/app ubuntu:16.04` but it's not working, my directory in Docker still empty.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996205/docker-mount-volume-from-windows-host) post and it doesn't help.

**UPD: Solved.**

Important step was to go to Docker `Settings > Shared Drives` and **uncheck** and **check** your shared drive again.

Then you can mount your volume like this:
`docker run -v /host_mnt/c/Users/User/Path:/docker/path image`

Comment: No dialog pop up ask you give permission or you miss it?

Answer (score 2):

This command should fix it .

docker run -it `-v ${PWD}:/app` ubuntu:16.04

Not sure what error you got, so I am assuming

- your host directory may not be correct.(solution is based on this)
- Permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permissions of your folders and user permission

Comment: I do it as admin, not sure what you mean about folder permission, it is default user directory and in docker it's on Shared Drive.

Comment: If you use linux, use chmod 777 on your root folder, then use docker commands